# npm build (react-scipts build) fails with no stacktrace

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I'm running `npm run build` which executes `react-scripts build` under the hood.

The script runs but then fails with the following:

```
> react-scripts build

Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined
```

If I run `npm run build --verbose` it fails with the following:

```
...
Creating an optimized production build...ad:flatten Completed in 2ms
Failed to compile.░⸩ ⠧ : timing config:load:flatten Completed in 2ms

Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined


npm timing command:run-script Completed in 7029ms
```

I have searched high and low for what might have caused this error, and have found nothing in my codebase that I've recently changed.

Things I've tried:

- deleted package-lock.json & the node_modules folder and reinstalled via npm install
- cleared the npm cache

I'd ultimately like to be shown where this issue is located, but I'm not sure how to tell react-scripts how to do this.

Whats the best way to do this?

Comment: `npm react-scripts --inspect-brk build`  and then launch node debugger and enable break on exception..

Comment: @ChandraKumar Thank you, I just tried this with vscode and the debugger never stops, even though it says it's attached. I get the same error. 

Comment: Debugger will not stop unless you connect it to node debugger and once the build is completed it will be stopped automatically. Also it doesnt resolve the error it only breaks on exception.